# convert active storage images to a different format, png to jpg for instance

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-activestorage

I wanted to convert images to jpeg/jpg, basically doing this:

```rb
  def show
    respond_to do |format|
      format.jpg do
        send_data(
          @event.image.variant(???).download,
          disposition: :inline,
          type: "image/jpeg"
        )
      end
    end
  end
```

Answer (score 0):

I needed to add `gem "vips"` to my `Gemfile`, and do:

```rb
 @event.image.variant(format: :jpg).download
```

See the related pull request that was merged: https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/40226/files